# Mysterious .directories in my home directory

Tags: directory, home-directory, hidden-files

I discovered some mysterious directories in my home.

Every one has dot before name.
They can't be seen from file explorer or even terminal, for example I'm using Eclipse "open file" for seeing them. 
They are called for example ".arduino", ".mozilla", ".local"...

My question is: What are they? Are they bad? Why are they messing my home? Is it like apps data?

Comment: Just to complement saiarcot895 answer: they begin with a dot because that makes the directory hidden. You can see them in file explorer pressing Ctrl+H (again to disable) and in termial using `ls -la` for example instead of `ls`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Files with a dot at the beginning of the name are hidden by default. In Nautilus (Ubuntu's default file manager) you can make them visible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. For the `ls` command, add the switch `-a` to it, which lists all files.

These files are either there from the beginning (like `.local` or `.config`) or are created by a program to store configuration etc.

As an example, PlayOnLinux stores its virtual drives in `~/.PlayOnLinux`. Java will create the `.java` directory, and Firefox and Thunderbird use the `.mozilla` directory. There are also files, not only directories. E.g. `.bash_history` contains the command history of your terminal shell.

So don't worry about these files. As a "normal" user, who doesn't mess with his systems config, you'll most likelynever even need to take a look into these files and directories.

Comment: In fact I was just curious. I used to change some system config files. Thank you for your good explaination.

Answer (score 4):

Those are configuration directories (or application data) for programs and are normal. `.arduino` is likely for the Arduino IDE, and `.mozilla` is for Mozilla Firefox. `.local/share` is used by many different applications.

Comment: Also many store in `~/.config/application_name`, e.g. Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

think of it as your %USERPROFILE%\AppData for Linux.
But unlike WinAPI, it actually works.